# How to make GameObjects Solid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So i want to make my first game, and it is with driving. I import a car and a race mape (Lake Race Tack) from Unity Assets Store,and when i drive my car enter se mountains,rocks 'n trees. How can i make the map solid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have solid shading, you should use the edge split modifier on the mesh. You can have it split edges that are marked sharp, by angle, or both. Make sure you check "Generate Colliders" on your mesh's import options.
I found a simple solution to this answer. Select the object you want to make solid and click "Add Component" then go to physics>mesh collider> check convex and add a material and mesh . This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To Make Objects Solid you need to add **[COLLIDERS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)** to the objects so that the objects don't pass through each other.